# Replace MS Office (Word) Integration

Tags: microsoft-office, integration

For years I have been helping clients replace Microsoft Office with free alternatives like OpenOffice and LibreOffice. Until today, I have always been able to find a way to replace MS Office functionality.

My client (a healthcare office) has software (Centricity by GE) which is able to generate letters such as appointment and late payment notices. Now that I have uninstalled MS Office, whenever they try to generate their letters they get this error: "MBCWordRuntime: Microsoft Word is not installed on this system, you cannot run this report without Microsoft Word 6.0 or higher.

[image: MBCWordRuntime Error]

They also print letters from one of their vendors websites (which only works in IE11) that does not allow them to print unless it detects they have Word installed. I assume these pieces of software are accessing MS Word's mail merge features.

Is there anything out there that can pretend to be Word so that I can avoid having to purchase a license just so they can print some letters from old software?

My client is running Windows 10.

Comment: I doubt it. This is likely controlled by a required API in the application they require. You could ask the support for this software package for alternatives, but I'd imagine they haven't accounted for people not using MS Office.